# CSS overlapping element blocking image hover

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm building a web page that displays images of cats, and I want to add a rating system on top of each image that allows users to like the cat. I've got the rating system to display when the user hovers over the image, but the rating system is blocking a part of the image, so when I hover over that part, the image hover effect is not registered.

I've tried setting the pointer-events property to none on the rating system, but then the heart icon in the rating system can't be clicked. When I set pointer-events to all, the blocking image problem is back.

Here's my current code for one cat image:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
  const catUrl = "https://placekitten.com/300/300";

  return (
    <div className="image-container">
      <img
        src={catUrl}
        alt="img"
        className="img"
        onMouseOver={() => setIsHovered(true)}
        onMouseOut={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      />
      <div className={isHovered ? "rate show" : "rate"}>
        <img
          src={
            !isLiked
              ? "https://i.ibb.co/MMBpKMV/heart-2.png"
              : "https://i.ibb.co/BV2CwZK/heart-1.png"
          }
          alt="heart-2"
          border="0"
          className="heart-icon"
          onClick={() => setIsLiked(true)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.rate {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}

.heart-icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width:fit-content
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could do it all with CSS? apply a `:hover` to the parent element. Or move your mouseover logic to the parent element.

Comment: @pilchard if I use :hover, then I cant switch between show class and rate show class. and how would it help since the rating part will still be overlapping and blocking the img hover

Comment: For both options I recommended attaching them to the parent, not the img

Comment: I still don't understand how does it help with solving the problem :( Using :hover will still not solve how the rate section will block the img, making the img not register the hover.

Comment: If you apply it to the parent element there is no blocking, see my answer

Comment: tysmm! it workss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all the `mouseOver` logic and simply add a `:hover` rule to the parent element.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
  const catUrl = "https://placekitten.com/300/300";

  return (
    <div className="image-container">
      <img
        src={catUrl}
        alt="img"
        className="img"
      />
      <div className="rate">
        <img
          src={
            !isLiked
              ? "https://i.ibb.co/MMBpKMV/heart-2.png"
              : "https://i.ibb.co/BV2CwZK/heart-1.png"
          }
          alt="heart-2"
          border="0"
          className="heart-icon"
          onClick={() => setIsLiked(true)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.image-container:hover .rate {
  display: flex;
}
```

Simple CSS only vanilla example.

```js
document.querySelector('.overlap').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('red');
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.base {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

.overlap {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}

.container:hover .overlap {
  display: block;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="base"></div>
  <div class="overlap"></div>
</div>
```